# Oldstylenums with Latin Modern (MiKTeX 2.9)

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex, oldstylenums, latin-modern

I'd like do get the nice oldstyle-numbers in my entire document. (Would there be a reason not to want them anywhere in a literature paper?) I use pdfTeX 1.40.11 via MiKTeX 2.9 and Latin Modern (`lmodern`) as a font. It seems like I should go for [`cfr-lm`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cfr-lm/) package, or are there alternatives?

What do I have do to to get `cfr-lm` working? The [installation description](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cfr-lm/doc/fonts/cfr-lm/cfr-lm.pdf) unfortunately isn't suited for MiKTeX.

My standard documentclass is `article`. Here are some of the packages I load by default, in case they make any difference:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
```

Comment: Doesn't MikTeX come with `cfr-lm` allready installed? At least it should be available through the MikTeX package manager.

Comment: @Caramdir Usually the package manager works just fine, but if I compile a minimal just containing the above packages and `cfr-lm`, I get the following error message:

`!pdfTeX error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe (file 
dd-lmr10): Font dd-lmr10 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: Just in case: You shouldn't load `lmodern` as well as `cfr-lm`. Also, you do not need to load `fontenc` if the only encoding you need is T1 (and TS1 for textcomp) though this one won't do any harm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the `cfr-lm` package is included in MiKTeX 2.9, the "map" files that include information necessary for TeX to use this font still need to be updated. Do the following:

- In the command prompt, run `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`; this opens `updmap.cfg` (usually in notepad);
- Add the line `Map clm.map` at the end of `updmap.cfg` (and save the file);
- In the command prompt, run `updmap`.

Note: Part 4 of [Installing TeX fonts](http://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) gives similar advice; however, running `updmap` is replaced by running `initexmf --mkmaps`. Anyway, the first method worked for me (MiKTeX 2.9, single-user install).

Comment: Now we're getting to regions of using and modifying LaTeX that I've never been to, please help me out here: With _command prompt_ you're just referring to the standard Windows [cmd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt) (I'm on Win7)? Do I need to navigate to a specific folder first before carrying out your steps 1 and 3? If I just open cmd and enter your first line, I get an empty document in notepad; where should I save the file?

Comment: @doncherry: Yes, `cmd` should be the right thing (I'm on a German Win7). No, no specific folder is needed. The document shouldn't be empty, but contain the (comment) line `%% T1 font configuration settings. See the MiKTeX manual for help.`. If it's empty, add `Map clm.map` and proceed as described.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, now it all works! Is it possible though that the file I edited was `updmap.cfg` and not `updmap.sys`?

Comment: @doncherry: Of course -- I edited my answer.