# problems with Venturis ADF and Iwona fonts in MiKTeX

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex

Running

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venturis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Hello, World! 0123456789 Hamburgers!
\end{document}
```

through `pdflatex` gives me

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file t1-yvtrc): Font t1-yvtrc at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

even though I have installed `venturis` in the MiKTeX Package Manager. There are folders for Venturis in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts` and in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex`. What should I do?

Same thing for Iwona.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14274/oldstylenums-with-latin-modern-miktex-2-9

Comment: Sounds like one or more Map files aren't being found (or even searched). Installing a font-related package via MikTeX's package manager may not always guarantee that the font map file is added to list of files to be searched. I suggest you look at the venturis documentation -- start with the README file -- and check if there's something more you need to do to enable its proper functioning.

Comment: Normally this problem can have two source: 1. a bug in the miktex package so that is forgets to enable the map-file. Or 2. miktex does enables the map-file but you as have local map-files the change can not be seen. To get around 2.: Check the path of the pdftex.map used by pdflatex. If it is in your user path run `updmap` on the command line.

Comment: You don't need to load `fontenc` separately if you only need the T1 encoding. `venturis` will load it anyway as the support files only support T1.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone who commented. I just ran `updmap` in my command prompt and then everything worked. Perhaps I'll try to get a better understanding of this stuff when I have time.